# Create JSON with same elements in PHP

Tags: php, json

I might be missing something obvious but is it possible to create a JSON like this with `json_encode`?

```
{
    'foo': 'bar',
    'foo': 'baz'
}
```

**UPDATE**

I had to note from the start that I'm aware that what I'm asking smells bad. However this is what SOLR is requiring. See https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-SendingJSONUpdateCommands

Comment: I believe the JSON standard calls for double quotes rather than singles. So that's not really JSON unfortunately. As for the same variable twice, that also violates the JSON standard. I think you'd have to implement your own version of `json_encode`. That said, you may want to reconsider whatever you're doing as the results of doing this may be that most dreaded, undefined behavior.

Comment: Assuming you can make your json string valid, you could do `var_export(json_decode($your_json));`

Comment: in this case you always get the value of last one

Comment: I had to note that I'm aware that what I'm asking is not right. However this is what SOLR is requiring. See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) won't give you a result with duplicate keys, since the object/array you're encoding cannot have had multiple values for one property/key, but you could store the same data a couple different ways. The most natural is probably:

```
{
    "foo": ["bar", "baz"]
}
```

You could also do something like:

```
[
   { 
     "key": "foo",
     "value": "bar"
   }, 
   { 
     "key": "foo",
     "value": "baz"
   }
]
```

If you must obtain that syntax for SOLR, you can obtain it by combining multiple calls to json_encode, although it isn't pretty:

```
$foo1 = [ 'foo' => 'bar' ];
$foo2 = [ 'foo' => 'baz' ];

echo rtrim( json_encode( $foo1 ), '}' ) . ',' . ltrim( json_encode( $foo2 ), '{' );
// {"foo":"bar","foo":"baz"}
```